# WSO2 AM 2.0.0 docker images in docker.wso2.com are not public

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to test the pattern-3 of the am 2.0.0 listed in [docker-apim](https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/master/docker-compose/pattern-3).
But it needs to login to docker.wso2.com. Why is this restricted for public and what is the way if a person outside wso2 to try these?

Comment: You can create an account at wso2.com and then  you should be able to login to that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an account at wso2.com and then you should be able to login to that.

Comment: I created account at the site but when I run `docker login docker.wso2.com` and enter the credentials I used I still get unauthorized access message...

Answer (score 0):

You can create user account by registering at https://wso2.com/user/register